# Referencing input value by name in HTMX

Tags: htmx

I've started looking into using HTMX recently and I've ran accross a problem that I can't figure out. Essentially I have a **select** element which I use to make an http **POST** whenever the user makes a selection. In order to make that post however, I need to provide a token which is stored in the **input** about the **select**. Is there a way for me to reference in HTMX syntax the input from above using it's name "csrfmiddlewaretoken"?

[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the `[name='csrf_token]` with `[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']`. That should work. Also if you move the `hx-post` to the form element, or to an alement that wraps the select and token input, the request payload should include both.

Comment: Yea that worked, needed to know the documentation better. The problem that I'm having with the form is that I need to include another value in the POST method and using hx-vals does not seem to work for a form when doing the submit

Comment: I'm surprised hx-vals didn't work. If you include the code example with hx-vals we might be able to help. Could you also use text rather than images for code samples? The text in that image is so tinsy winsy.

Comment: I figured out that I misunderstood the library and needed more reading. I'll post the answer to my issue

Answer (score 2):

So I figured out what my trouble was. In order for me to expand the payload of the **hx-post** request, what I needed to do was include the HTML elements that I wanted the contents of in the **hx-post** request. To do that you can use the **hx-include** attribute on the request emiting element, which references other elements by name and takes their value in the payload as a {name: value} pair.

```
<select name="sample_select" hx-post="link" hx-include="[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']" hx-trigger="changed">...
```

The example select above would issue an HTTP Post request when the value of the select element would be changed. The request payload would then be

```
{
 sample_select: selected_value;
 csrfmiddlewaretoken: value
}
```

Keep in mind that if you have multiple elements on the same page with the same name, when you reference the name in the **hx-include** attribute then the HTMX library will take all the values from all the elements in the payload. I have not found a way to reference a specific element, or the closest one yet but if you know of a way please share.

Comment: Wouldn't this allow you to get to the one you want? [official docs on #targets](https://htmx.org/docs/#targets)